# Error analysis of a measured physical quantity

Tags: distributions, measurement-error

I have a set of 100 data point pairs, representing the estimated $(x_{\mathrm{est}},y_{\mathrm{est}})$ position coordinates of a physical object, calculated based on sensor range measurements. Knowing the exact ground-truth position coordinates $(x_{\mathrm{true}},y_{\mathrm{true}})$ of the object, what is a good choice of error metric $(e_{x}=x_{\mathrm{true}}-x_{\mathrm{est}},e_{y}=y_{\mathrm{true}}-y_{\mathrm{est}}$, or $\big\|e_{\{\cdot\}}\big\|)$, and how to visually represent (in a plot) the error distribution of the calculated position to perform an error analysis?

Thanks for any idea you can offer.

Comment: This is a question about the properties of the sensor and how the calculation is performed.  We can't answer it without that information.  Could you include them in an edit to this post?

Comment: @whuber: Thanks. I am actually not looking to characterize the sensor measurement error, given that I already have the ground truth and the measured values, but rather to visually represent the calculated errors in x and y. I hope the edit clarifies this better.